# Post excel file from Vuejs into Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I want to post and excel file which is on my local drive into a Laravel app. But I'm getting the error message below and I don't know if I'm not sending the file correctly through axios or not receiving it on the Laravel side.

Here is my Javascript file:

```
// import { LocalStorage } from 'quasar'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'
import { PythonShell } from 'python-shell'
import axios from 'axios'
const FormData = require('form-data')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const options = {
  // mode: 'text',
  // pythonPath: 'path/to/python',
  // pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
  scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, '/../rpa')
  // args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
}

const exportDir = 'C:\\TEMP\\TFMCH\\'

export const rpa = {
tfmch_LX02 (warehouse, filePath, truncate) {
    console.log('Updating LX02 on TFMCH')
    const URL = 'http://localhost/tfmch_LARAVEL/public/api/' + 'rpa/lx02'
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('lx02', fs.createReadStream(filePath))
    formData.append('truncate', truncate)
    const formConfig = {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }
    console.log(URL)
    console.log(fs.createReadStream(filePath))
    // console.log(filePath)
    // console.log(formData)
    // console.log(formConfig)

    axios.post(URL, formData, formConfig)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        // if (warehouse === 805) {
        //   rpa.sap_LX02_wh(804, false)
        // }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
        // console.log('error')
      })
  }
}
```

And this is my Laravel API:

```
Route::post('rpa/lx02', function(Request $request){

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

// return response();

if ($request->truncate) {
    LX02::query()->truncate();
}

$contents = file_get_contents($request->lx02->path());
// return response($contents);

Excel::import(new LX02Import, $contents);

$config = new Upload;
$config->table_name = 'LX02';
$config->save();

// $deletedRows = lx02::where('sloc', 'LIKE', 'S%')->delete();

return response()->json("Updated");
```

});

And I get the error message from Laravel:

```
{
"message": "Call to a member function path() on string",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
"file": "C:\\Users\\Ingo\\Google Drive\\1 - Webapps\\tfmch_LARAVEL\\routes\\api.php",
"line": 458,
"trace": [
```

Comment: what `dd($request->lx02)` print u?

Comment: `dd($request->lx02)` gives me an error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/tfmch_LARAVEL/public/api/import/lx02' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: I can make it work using Postman. If I export Postman's code to Axios, the only difference from my code above is this line: `headers: { ...data.getHeaders()  },` Which if I add it there I get the following error: `"TypeError: data.getHeaders is not a function"`